# PassportJS Access-Control-Allow-Headers when making Express redirect

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, angular2-routing

I'm receiving the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4200/#/partners. Request
>   header field content-type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

server.js snippet:

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next){
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', "true");
     next();
 });

 .
 .
 .

 app.post("/login", function(req, res, next) {
     passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info) {
       if (err) { return next(err); }
       if (!user){ return res.redirect(home_connection+'/#/'); }

       req.logIn(user, function(err){
         if(err){ return next(err); }
         return res.redirect(home_connection+"/#/partners");
       });
     })(req, res, next);
   }
 );
```

Keep in mind that this error still persists even after I set the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers. The path that Express is to redirect to is an Angular2 route, `/#/partners`.

Comment: What is the value of `home_connection`? Is it a different origin than the request origin?

Comment: Yes, they're different. The request origin is localhost:8080, the `home_connection` variable is localhost:4200.

Comment: My node.js server is running on 8080 and my angular2 server is running on 4200, would the error be solved if I merged the two onto the same server, if so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Whatever is listening to that port needs to respond with the Access-Control headers as well.

Comment: If you're making an ajax call to post to /login you should probably just respond with JSON that contains information on where to redirect. Don't do the redirect server-side in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I used Angular2 to redirect instead of the Node server.**

Rather than redirecting to the path within the Node server, I just returned a success confirmation as the response. When Angular2 receives the success confirmation it then routes the app to the proper location.

I modified `/login` to the following:

```
app.post("/login", cors(),
  passport.authenticate("local"),
    function(req, res){
      res.status(200).json(req.user);
});
```

Notice `res.status(200).json(req.user);` simply returns the user object.

The snippet of Angular2 code that calls `/login` looks like (keep in mind `loginUser` is a function in `UserService` that calls posts to `/login`):

```
this.userService
  .loginUser(this.user.phone, this.third.value.code.replace(/ /g, ''))
  .then((resp) => {
    if(resp) this.router.navigate(['/partners']);
    else {
      this.third.setValue({"code":""});
      this.invalidCode = true;
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    this.invalidCode = true;
  });
```

Note that `this.router.navigate(['/partners']);` handles the redirection to `/partners`.